# Mutate a state by programmatically selecting a nested property

Tags: angular, typescript, state-management, ngxs

I am struggling to use NGXS's internal API to mutate a deeply nested property in my state.

Since NGXS's states are immutable, my current (less than ideal) solution is to recreate a state instance, then hydrating it with the contents of my old state, with a condition about the one property I want mutated.

My state model :

```
interface TaskStateModel {
  tasks: Tasks;
}
```

The `Tasks` class :

```
export class Tasks { // I have obfuscated the property names
property1: UniqueTask[]
proprety2: UniqueTask[]
// etc...
  constructor(init?: Partial<Tasks>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

The `UniqueTask` class :

```
export class UniqueTask { // Only including the relevant properties
taskIds: string[];
asssignedUserName: string;

  constructor(init?: Partial<UniqueTask>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

The `assignTask` Action :

```
  export class AssignTask {
    static readonly type = '[Task] Assign Task';

    constructor(public taskIds: string[], public taskType: string) {}

  }
```

Here is my current solution :

```
  @Action(AssignTask)
  assignTasks(ctx: StateContext<TaskStateModel>, action: AssignTask) {
    return this.taskService.assignTasks(action.taskIds).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          action.taskIds.forEach(taskId => {
            const state = ctx.getState();
            const newState: TaskStateModel = {tasks: new Tasks()};
            const taskIndexToBeAssigned = state.tasks[action.taskType].findIndex(task => task.taskIds.includes(taskId));
            Object.keys(state.tasks).forEach(property => {
              if (property !== action.taskType) {
                newState.tasks[property] = state.tasks[property];
              }
              else {
                newState.tasks[property] = state.tasks[property].map((task, index) => {
                  const assignedUserName = (taskIndexToBeAssigned === index) ? this.currentUserService.currentUser.name : task.assignedUserName;
                  return new UniqueTask({
                    ...task,
                    assignedUserName
                  });
                });
              }
            });
            ctx.setState(newState);
          });
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

The Action `AssignTask` sends a `taskType` to select the desired property, and a `taskId`, to select the element within the array whose property is to be mutated.

My objective is to achieve the same result with the `setState`, `patch`, and `updateItem` methods.

For what it's worth, here is my attempt to do it on my own :

```
  @Action(AssignTask)
  assignTasks(ctx: StateContext<TaskStateModel>, action: AssignTask) {
    return this.taskService.assignTasks(action.taskIds).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          action.taskIds.forEach(taskId => {
            ctx.setState(patch({
              tasks: patch({
                [action.taskType] : updateItem<UniqueTask>(task => task.taskIds(taskId), // [action.taskType] cannot be used as a programmatic property selector here
                  task => {
                    return {...task, assignedUserName: this.currentUserService.currentUser.name};
                  })
              })
            }));
          });
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: My apologies, I had changed the Tasks and UniqueTask classes to interfaces in my question, without realizing that I instantiated them later on...
I originally did this to try to reduce the complexity of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use this ngxs labs package
https://npmjs.com/package/@ngxs-labs/immer-adapter

Import `ImmutableContext`

```
import { ImmutableContext } from '@ngxs-labs/immer-adapter';
```

Implementation

```
export const AUTH_STATE_TOKEN = new StateToken<AuthStateModel>('auth');

export const authDefaults: AuthStateModel = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  signInProvider: 0,
  profile: {
    loaded: false,
    displayName: '',
    photoURL: ''
  },
  request: {
    firebase: {
      loaded: false, 
      length: 0,
      errors: null, 
      data: null
    }
  }
};

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: AUTH_STATE_TOKEN,
  defaults: authDefaults
})
```

Action

```
  @Action(MyAction)
  @ImmutableContext()
  sampleFunction({ setState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: MyAction) {
    setState((state: MyStateModel) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.signInProvider = SignInProvider.SocialMedia;
      state.profile.loaded = true;
      state.profile.displayName = displayName;
      state.profile.photoURL = defaultImage(displayName);
      state.request.firebase.loaded = !!action.state;
      state.request.firebase.length = action.state ? 1 : 0;
      state.request.firebase.data = action.state;
      return state;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need.
If there really is no clean way of doing what I want without an external dependency then I will mark your answer as accepted.
Many thanks.

Comment: You can also look here for other ways on how update deeply nested properties https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/immutability-helpers

Comment: If you want to avoid deeply nested updates you might want to use sub states https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/sub-states